# Superfish menus getting clipped in blocks

Tags: 7, theming, navigation

I'm showing a Superfish block with a selected menu in the [Homebox](https://www.drupal.org/project/homebox) module.

The problem is that child menus are getting clipped in the left and right and using browser console I'm not able to remove this clipping either by `z-index` or using `overflow-x/y` css properties.

[image: Portfolio for students is clipped]

How to make it work?

The div enclosing the Quick Links Staff block has "`overflow`" set to "`hidden`". Now if I disable it then the sub-menus show correctly but now the block height drops :

[image]

Comment: Can be that the menu and container are in different z-index stacks and upping the z-index will thus have no effect.  [What No One Told You About Z-Index](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't remove it with `z-index: 4;` then it might mean that your menu does not have a background; thus, it's transparent.

So add a background to your menu ex: `background: white;`